# Making index.max_result_window setting persistent

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Is there a way to make **index.max_result_window** setting persistent.
Also what are the available options to push this setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could do that by altering *conf/elasticsearch.yml*. Just add a line to the end with something like

```
index.max_result_window: 1
```

and it will be set after next restart of the Elasticsearch

Comment: For future reference, this does not work any more in ES 5+.

Answer (score 5):

You have 3 options to set this parameter:

- Set it into the elasticsearch.yml (as @Mysterion said).
- Set it into a mapping template, basically is a schema of your index used when the data is inject in ES. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html
- Set it dynamically via the indice_update_setting API https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html

HtH,

Comment: Thank you! It really helped me!

Answer (score 2):

Since this was tagged with `nest`, I assume you were looking for a way to do it strongly typed with nest. You can also set it upon indexcreation like this (here setting `max_result_window` to 20k):

```cs
await _elasticClient.CreateIndexAsync(
    "name_of_my_index",
    c => c
        .InitializeUsing(new IndexState
        {
            Settings = new IndexSettings {{"index.max_result_window", 20000}}
        })
);
```

This was done with Nest v6.2.0.

Kibana confirmation afterwards:
[image]